# Retornar valor DataLayer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Boa tarde.

tenho uma procedure que faz alguns comandos e retorna
0 = sucesso;
1 = sem sucesso;

```
 alter PROCEDURE [dbo].TesteRetorno
    (
        @DS_NOME_ARQUIVO_SINCRONISMO AS VARCHAR(200) = null
    )

    AS

    if exists(select top 1 ID_USUARIO from BCS_USUARIO where ID_USUARIO = 'brisa')
    begin

    return 0 

    end 

    else
return 1
```

gostaria de usar esse retorno no meu código C#.

```
    ParameterCollection oP = new ParameterCollection();
    oP.Add("@DS_NOME_ARQUIVO_SINCRONISMO", "", DbType.String);

    var retorno = DataLayer.ExecuteNonQuery("TesteRetorno", oP).ToString();
```

Mas nunca recebo nada de retorno;

segue a classe do DataLayer

```
#region Assembly brsBiblioteca.dll, v1.0.3.0
// C:\Users\ctorres\Documents\Projetos\FSLexMark\Legado\FRAMEWORK v3.5\LEXMARK\SAP\MigracaoSAP_V4\Packages\brsBiblioteca.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Data;

namespace Biblioteca.Data
{
    public sealed class DataLayer
    {
        public DataLayer();

        public static void ExecutarCommand(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static void ExecutarCommand(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters, string strConexao);
        public static void ExecutarCommand(IDbConnection objConnection, IDbTransaction objTransaction, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string pstrCommandText);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters, string strConexao);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDataset(IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction tran, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDatasetNoTransaction(string pstrCommandText);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDatasetNoTransaction(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDatasetNoTransaction(IDbConnection conn, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static DataSet ExecuteDatasetNoTransaction(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters, string strConexao);
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string pstrCommandText);
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string pstrCommandText, ParameterCollection phtParameters, string strConexao);
        public static int ExecuteNonQuery(IDbConnection objConnection, IDbTransaction objTransaction, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static object ExecuteScalar(string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static object ExecuteScalar(string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters, int Timeout);
        public static object ExecuteScalar(IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction tran, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters);
        public static object ExecuteScalar(IDbConnection conn, IDbTransaction tran, string pstrNomeStoredProcedure, ParameterCollection phtParameters, int TimeOut);
        public static IDbCommand GetCommand();
        public static IDbConnection GetConnection();
        public static IDbConnection GetConnection(string pstrConnectionString);
        public static IDbDataAdapter GetDataAdapter(IDbCommand cmd);
        public static DbType GetDbType(DbType pDbType);
        public static System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType GetOracleType(DbType pDbType);
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é `DataLayer`?

Comment: O Datalayer é uma biblioteca  da namespace Biblioceta.Data

Tambem posso fazer com outro comando.

Comment: Então precisa do código do método `ExecuteNonQuery`, não acha?

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: E a implementação do método, onde está?

Comment: pelo visto `ExecuteNonQuery` sempre irá retornar um int, talvez devesse usar o `ExecuteScalar` ou verificar se seria o caso de retornar o valor por parâmetro

Comment: não tenho a implementação do Método, é uma Biblioteca.

Comment: tem documentação pelo menos ?

Comment: Bá, jovem. Você precisa pelo menos saber como o método deve funcionar, senão tudo o que pode fazer é dar tiros no escuro.

Comment: @JuniorTorres tentou com o `ExecuteScalar ` ?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, esta um pouco mais difícil do que imaginava.

Pode fechar a questão por favor